# Understanding the proof of AEP theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

I'm trying to understand AEP(Asymptotic Equipartition Property) theorem but I couldn't understand following result:

> Let $X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables which take on the values from finite alphabet $\mathcal{X}$ and $X_i\sim P_X$. Prove that $$P_X(X_1,X_2, \dots , X_n) = P_X(X_1)P_X(X_2)\dots P_X(X_n)$$

We know in general that functions of independent RVs are also independent RVs but how does this help us to prove the result? Also I don't understand exactly the meaning of $$P_X(X_1,X_2, \dots , X_n) \tag{1}$$ By definition $$P_{X^n}(x_1 , x_2, \dots , x_n) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = x_1,X_2 = x_2, \dots , X_n = x_n)$$but $(1)$ is really confusing because arguments are RVs instead of certain values and it seems self-referential.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you should go for something like $P(x_1,\dots,x_n):=\mathbb P(Y_1=x_1,\dots,Y_n=x_n)$ where the $Y_i$ have the same distribution as the $X_i$ and are independent wrt the $X_i$. Then it is not self referential anymore.

Comment: @drhab Sorry, I'm still confused. It should be a function of random variables but in that case it isn't.

Comment: If $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ as a function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ and $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are random variables then also $P(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is a random variable, period. It might be that $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is defined in a way that somehow made use of the rv's $X_i$ but that does not really matter. Things might get confusing though by substituting the $X_i$ in an expression that is defined by means of the same $X_i$.